# angular 2 bootstrap CSS not loading

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I started a new angular 2 project with ng-bootstrap. I can see the bootstrap js working fine, but not the CSS. Do I need to include those CSS explicitly, which I doubt would be the case, but I may be wrong too.

I even tried adding the bootstrap.css in my component, but nothing happened. Adding it on index.html does make the difference but I didn't want to call explicitly unless there is no other way.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using angular-cli ?

Comment: yes, I installed through https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started, and starting the server through ng serve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glyphicon are no longer supported in Bootstrap 4, so missing fonts were the root cause rather than css.

Dropped the Glyphicons icon font. If you need icons, some options are:
the upstream version of Glyphicons
Octicons
Font Awesome

src: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answer, it could help others who stumble upon the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `angular-cli` you can add the path to your global css files in the `angular-cli.json` file to add it globally:

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/path/to/bootstrap.css",
   "styles.css"
]
```

Comment: It didn't bring any style in my code: <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"
                [class.highlighted]="iLike"
                (click)="click()">
  </i>

Comment: And it also overwrite my existing style, so it is pulling the css. It might be the case that probably  glyphicon would be missing into it.

Comment: you're probably missing the font not the CSS

Comment: But I didn't found any font in bootstrap, do we have manually include it somewhere?

Comment: No, they comme with the bootstrap module : http://imgur.com/GDZxaaN
Did you `npm install bootstrap` ? If I'm not mistaking ng2-bootstrap contains only the components not the css files.

Comment: Yes I installed through `npm install bootstrap` and I can see the downloaded css and js in the node_modules

Comment: And there are no font folder ? (Like on my screenshot)

Comment: I can't see any font folder, so you may be right. It seems it hasn't installed font, unless there is no font used in ng-bootstrap and glyphicon also is not part of it, and so its not supported. Can't see you screenshot too :(